# search array of words in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have text :

```
$a = I wanna eat apple , and banana .
```

I wanna get every words and punctuation of that sentence :

```
$b = explode(' ', strtolower(trim($a)));
```

the result of explode is array.
I have a words table on db that has fields :

```
id, word and typewords
```

all in lowercase. but for punctuation there are no exist in db.
I wanna search every words in db to take the type of words, so the final result that i want to get is :
`words/typeofwords` =

```
I/n wanna/v eat/v apple/n ,/, and/p banana/n ./.
```

here's the code :

```
function getWord ($word){
$i = 0 ;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT typewords FROM words WHERE word = '$word' ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         $word[$i] = $row['typewords'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $word;
}

echo $b.'/'.getWord($b);
```

but it doesn't work, please help me, thanks !

Comment: @RonakPatel blank result

Comment: dump you query and check directly in database.

Comment: @RonakPatel NULL, are my query is correct for array ? the problem is maybe in my `words` table there are no data of puctuation (,. etc), so i have to make if condition of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
function getWord($words){
    $association = array();
    foreach($words as $word)
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT typewords FROM words WHERE word = '$word' ");
        if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
            $association[$word] = $row['typewords'];
        elseif(preg_match('/[\.\,\:\;\?\!]/',$word)==1)
            $association[$word] = $word;
    }
    return $association;
}

$typewords = getWord($b);
foreach($b as $w)
    echo $w.'/'.$typewords[$w];
```

Comment: oh, thank you very much , but how about the punctuation ? there are no data of punctuation in word field, so punctuation must give result itself, eg : `./.`, `,/,`

Comment: I fixed it in order to recognize punctuation and behave correctly! If you need, you can add/remove punctuation recognition (at the moment it recognizes the following `. , : ; ? !`)

Answer (score 0):

You assume the function parameter to be an array, but it is a string.

Edit: In your function you treat `$word` as an array as well as a string. Decide what you want and recode your function.

Comment: so I have to make it array so i can access that row of string?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWord($word){

    // concat the word your searching for with the result
    // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(word,'/',typewords) as this_result FROM words WHERE word = '$word' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    return $row['this_result']." ";  // added a space at the end.
}

// loop through the $b array and send each to the function
foreach($b as $searchword) {
    echo getWord($searchword);
}
```